# rviz over Wifi "brw_upload_constant_buffer: Assertion" failed

Tags: ros, rviz, ros-master-uri

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have ros setup on two machines connected by wifi, one on my robot, the other on a laptop, using the ROS_MASTER_URI approach.  I've confirmed proper operation using the tutorials.

When I start rviz, it connects and brings up the gui for a spit second (I can see my robot model and everything as it should be), then crashes with this error:

rviz: brw_burbe.c:265: brw_upload_constant_buffer: Assertion 'brw->vs.constant_map[i] <= nr' failed.

Any idea what's happening or how to fix this?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36922/rviz-over-wifi-%22brw_upload_constant_buffer:-assertion%22-failed/) by [R. Meuth](https://answers.ros.org/users/2666/r.-meuth/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-06-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does this happen when you run ROS and Rviz on all one machine?  I don't think that the error you put is in any way related to the networking portions of rviz.

---

Originally posted by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) with karma: 6414 on 2012-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1